# Expand type synonyms, type families with GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, type-families

I am wondering if there is functionality that exists within GHCi (or elsewhere) to expand type synonyms and families out of an arbitrary type expression.

For example, if I have these types,

```
data A = A
data B = B

data F a = F a
data G a = G a
data H a b = H a b

type S a b = H (F a) (G b)
type T a = S (a) (H B a)

type family R a :: *
type instance R (H a b) = H b a
```

then I would like to be able to get this kind of output in a ghci session.

```
> :t undefined :: T (S B A)
undefined :: T (S B A) :: T (S B A)

> :texpand undefined :: T (S B A)
undefined :: T (S B A) :: H (F ((H (F B) (G A)))) (G (H B (H (F B) (G A))))

> :texpand undefined :: R (T (S B A))
undefined :: R (T (S B A)) :: H (G (H B (H (F B) (G A)))) (F ((H (F B) (G A))))
```

As far as I can tell, GHCi doesn't actually provide anything like a `:texpand` command, and I'm not sure that it would be the best interface for that information anyway.  However, it seems likely that expanded types can be extracted from GHC somehow, and I would really like to be able to see them interactively.

Hacks, documentation links, speculative discussion about future additions to GHCi all welcome.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`:kind!` will do that:

```
λ> :kind! T (S B A)
T (S B A) :: *
= H (F (H (F B) (G A))) (G (H B (H (F B) (G A))))
λ> :kind! R (T (S B A))
R (T (S B A)) :: *
= H (G (H B (H (F B) (G A)))) (F (H (F B) (G A)))
```

(For convenience, you can put something like `:def k! \x -> return (":kind! " ++ x)` in your `.ghci`.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is new as of GHC 7.something. (4 or 6, I forget)

Comment: This does not work for me in GHC 8.0.2. It just prints back the type aliases as is, without any expansion.

Comment: I have the same problem with GHC 8.2.1

Comment: It works again with GHC 9.2.1. See the [release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.2.1-alpha2/docs/html/users_guide/9.2.1-notes.html#ghci).